# $A$ and $B$ are similar.why there are $X$ and $Y$ s.t $A=XY$ and $B=YX$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

let $A,B \in {M_n}$, $A$ and $B$ are similar.why there are $X$ and $Y$ s.t $A=XY$ and $B=YX$  .                                                               (NOTE: $X$ or $Y$ is nonsingular)

Comment: **Hint**: What is the definition of matrix similarity?

Answer (score 4):

Note that if 
$$
B = S^{-1}AS
$$
For some invertible matrix $S$, then we have
$$
A = S(S^{-1}A)\\
B = (S^{-1}A)S
$$

Answer (score 0):

Two matrices are called similar if
\begin{equation}
B = X^{-1} A X
\end{equation}
For some (invertible) $n \times n $ matirx $X$. Also, we can write
\begin{equation}
A=Y^{-1} B Y
\end{equation}
From which we can see that
\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& Y^{-1} X^{-1} A X Y \\
  &=& (XY)^{-1} A XY
\end{eqnarray}
Do you think you could take it from here?